# Bankers Algorithm processes

Tags: algorithm, operating-system, bankers-algorithm

Using Bankers algorithm,

If a process (p1) is unable to complete by any other process p2,p3,p4 etc giving up it's resources singly, can they ALL relinquish their resources **together** so p1 could complete?

Or is that not a thing that could be done?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
Of course it's possible for processes to relinquish resources.  The problem is what sort of communication you're allowing among the processes, and where you're having trouble.  Since you failed to post any algorithmic description for the processes, let alone any code that isn't working, there's not much we can do to help ... *yet*.

Comment: @Prune there is no code, it's a question, maybe you've misinterpreted my question?

Comment: Then please clarify.  I explained a couple of points where I find the problem unclear.

Comment: You have for example, 3 processes: P1,P2,P3.. In your available vector lets say you have 1,1,1 available, but p1 requires 5,5,5. P2 has held resources of 3,3,3 and P3 has held recourses of 2,2,2. Now obviously, if P2 relinquishes it won't be enough, if P3 relinquishes it won't be enough. However, if they BOTH relinquish it will be enough. My question is, are BOTH of them releasing at the same time possible, or can it only be done one at a time?

Comment: Critical sections and inter-process communication are standard capabilities for processes.  What is it about yours that you think they might not be able to do that?

Comment: I just wasn't 100% sure if more than one process can give up it's resources, I wasn't sure if only 1 could give up at a time. I am only just learning this and was a little confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you asking about capabilities of abstract processes, or of the Banker's algorithm in particular?

If it's abstract processes, then yes, it's easily possible.  Create a signal `yield_all`, and code each process to relinquish the resources when it receives that signal.  Some master process will have to send the signal to each of P2, P3, and P4, and then allow P1 to proceed with its allocation.  Implementation details are up to the designer.

---

If you're asking about the Banker's algorithm, I'm not entirely clear what you need.  No allocation is allowed to proceed unless the system is still in a `safe state`: each process is capable of terminating (thus returning all resources) in some order, with the remaining system availability.

Thus, in the situation you describe, forcing any other process to yield resources is not a valid operation.  Rather, P1 has to wait until the others have terminated normally, before it is allowed to allocate the requested resources.  If this is not possible, then the system is in an `unsafe state` -- one or more prior requests should not have been granted.

Does that answer your question?